# Control access on Athena tables federated from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I used the DynamoDB connector https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/tree/master/athena-dynamodb to surface tables in Athena. The connector added all the tables from DynamoDb to the **default** database. Now I would like to hide some of the tables and control access to them in Athena. Is that possible with IAM or one should adjust the code of the connector?
Thanks,

Comment: are you using Glue catalogue and if yes have you tried https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/restrict-access-to-your-aws-glue-data-catalog-with-resource-level-iam-permissions-and-resource-based-policies/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can hide tables or control access with IAM in Federated Queries. The list of tables comes from the connector (the Lambda function deployed by the connector). Athena itself has no way to control permissions to tables, that's done in either Glue or Lake Formation when its "regular" tables, and in Federated Queries its delegated to the connector.

I think the closest you can get is to fork the connector and add your own logic to filter tables.